# Php function to avoid a repeating code

Tags: php

I am using the below code to split a string. And i have to repeat code for each input `$ProductsURL[x]` and output `$productx[]`

```
<?php
$url = "$ProductsURL[0]";
$urls = split("http://", $url);
$product0 = array();
foreach($urls as $val){
    if(!$val) continue;
    $product0[] = "http://$val";
}
?>
<?php
$url = "$ProductsURL[1]";
$urls = split("http://", $url);
$product1 = array();
foreach($urls as $val){
    if(!$val) continue;
    $product1[] = "http://$val";
}
?>
..................
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating the code for each input/output needed. I need the code ~100 times

Comment: Could you explain what your code does?

Comment: I have store in my data base the products URL`s in one string : http://www.example.com/p2http://example.com/p1 . and i split them with the above code to get $product0[1] to get the fisr product from a brand and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple loop. And use array variables as hashes to store data.

Also I think that you have error in the following line: `$url = "$ProductsURL[$i];"`.

Finally it should be something like that:

```
$product = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  $url = $ProductsURL[$i];
  $urls = split("http://", $url);
  $product[$i] = array();
  foreach($urls as $val){
    if(!$val) continue;
    $product[$i][] = "http://$val";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a function.
All you need is an old plain `foreach` loop.
And maybe some knowledge how work with `variable variables` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php
    foreach($ProductsURL as $key=>$url)
    {
        $urls = split("http://", $url);
        ${'product'.$key} = array();
        foreach($urls as $val) if($val) ${'product'.$key} [] = "http://$val";
    }
?>
```

Then, to check the outcome:

```
print_r($product0);
print_r($product1);
print_r($product2);
....
```

Comment: I would steer them towards `$product[0]` instead of `$product0`.

Comment: Me too. But this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Sometimes they ask for something because they don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = array();    
for ($i = 0; ; $i++) {
        if ($i > 1) {
            break;
        }
       $url = "$ProductsURL[$i]";
    $urls = split("http://", $url);

    foreach($urls as $val){
        if(!$val) continue;
        $product[$i][] = "http://$val";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables as variable names, using $$

```
<?php

foreach ($productURL as $key => $value) {
$newName = 'product' . $key;
$$newName[] = $value;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, I would choose to store all the products in an array instead of separate variables. The code you'd need should be something like:

```
<?php
$products = array();
foreach ($ProductsURL as $productUrl) {
    $product = array();
    $urls = split("http://", $url);
    foreach($urls as $val){
        if(!$val) continue;
        $product[] = "http://$val";
    }
    $products[] = $product;
}
?>
```